# How to compress output of arrays of primitive type?

Tags: arrays, json, jq, summarize

My json file contains arrays of ints and strings and objects. Is there a way of compressing the output of arrays that contain only ints or strings?

- either do not display elements of these arrays, or
- show type of elements and count

This is what it looks like now:

```
$ jq "." foo.json
{
    "version": [
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.3",
            "2.53.3",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.3",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.3",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.0",
            "2.53.3",
            "2.53.0"
          ],
    "walltime_seconds": [
            0.165,
            0.199,
            0.415,
            0.193,
            12.114,
            0.227,
            12.341,
            12.145,
            0.135,
            0.326,
            0.293,
            0.19,
            0.271,
            0.103,
            0.196,
            0.18,
            0.177,
            0.166,
            0.506,
            0.568
          ]
}
```

This is what I would like:

```
{
    "version": "[..]",
    "walltime_seconds": "[..]",

}
```

or this

```
{
    "version": "Array(str, 20)",
    "walltime_seconds": "Array(float, 20)",

}
```

Of course the compression should happen anywhere in the json tree and it should only be done for int, str, float and not for objects.

Comment: The outputs you have shown are not valid JSON

Comment: @Inian good point, I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def compress:
  if type == "array"
  then (if    all(.[]; type == "string") then "[string]"
        elif  all(.[]; type == "number") then "[number]"
        elif  all(.[]; type == "boolean") then "[boolean]"
        else .
        end)
  else .
  end;

walk(compress)
```

With your sample input, the result would be:

```
{
  "version": "[string]",
  "walltime_seconds": "[number]"
}
```

---

To include the length and handle arrays of `null`:

```
def compress:
  def check($t):
    if all(.[]; type == $t) then "[\($t)[\(length)]]" else empty end;
  if type == "array"
  then check("string") // check("number") // check("boolean") // check("null") // .
  else .
  end;
```

Comment: That's great, it works! Is there a way to store functions like `compress` somewhere?

Comment: One possibility would be to include it in a file: ~/.jq

Comment: that's so cool, works! Thank's a lot!